# Every time I take a database dump from production server and try to import and run on local, the migration is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I implemented `friendy_id` on my rails application. So I generate new `column` called `slug` in my existing ActiveRecord model called `Category`. Everything is working fine. Both my local code and production have same tables and columns. The same code is running on production.

Every now and then I take the mysql database dump from the production server and try to import it to the source code on my local machine. Before I run `rake db:migrate` I always do `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create`.

So After importing the dump I do drop and create and then run `rake db:migrate`. It fails. Saying **Duplicate column slug from categories**

So what I've been doing so far is, every time I import dump from production, I am supposed to drop the `slug` column by doing

```
ALTER TABLE categories DROP COLUMN slug;
```

Then When I run `rake db:migrate`. It runs the last migrations which is `created slug for categories`. And then the migration ends successfully.

How can I overcome this issue ? I am forced to this every time I want to import the production db to local.

Comment: Why do you run `rake db:migrate` when importing dump?

Comment: First I just tried running `rails s` directly after importing `dump.sql`. It gave `rake aborted`.

Comment: And last time I posted a similar question and explained situation a guy told me to do so. I just followed his solution. And it atleast solved the issue temporarily. And I don't get why people have to down vote the question for that.

Comment: Generally, you don't _need_ to drop/create/migrate db when importing dump. Especially __after__ importing the dump.

Comment: Exactly  generally @SergioTulentsev.

Comment: This doesn't mean you need to do it here. Clearly, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like your `schema_migrations` tables are no synced between production and development. So rails tries to migrate the last migration (adding slug) which is already added in the database, hence the error.